# Interpreting UDP video stream from an OpenCV/OpenGL application

Tags: opencv, udp, video-streaming, vlc, mjpeg

I have an existing application with OpenGL/OpenCV that can display image from Video4Linux cameras. I would like to transfer the image over ethernet to some other computer. Unfortunately, since the existing application already occupies the camera, I have to make sure the image transmission happens only from the existing OpenGL/OpenCV application that I have. I've searched internet and came up with two good resources:

[1] https://protecto.github.io/cpp-streaming-opencv-frames/

[2] http://derekmolloy.ie/udp-video-streaming-beaglebone-black/

Like ref.[1], I would like to stream OpenCV frames, since I am able to implement it in my application.  With a few modifications, I can now send OpenCV frames over UDP connection. The ambiguity for me is the interpretation of the stream.

```
std::vector<uchar> buf;
cv::imencode(".jpg", ACTUAL_FRAME, buf, std::vector<int>());

for (std::vector<uchar>::iterator it = buf.begin() ; it < buf.end(); it += chunk_size)
{
    std::vector<uchar>::iterator end = it + chunk_size;
    if (end >= buf.end()) {
        end = buf.end();
    }

    std::string msg_str(it, end);
    const void * msg = msg_str.c_str();
    if (sendto(sockfd, msg, chunk_size, 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1 )
    {
        printf("UDP Error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else{
        //printf("UDP Send Successful!\n");
        //fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

With the current implementation, data is sent as chunks that contains 64000 unsigned char. I am able to see the data flow in the UDP server. However, I don't know what is the actual standard way or format to stream mjpeg movies over UDP. For example, using VLC media player, as ref.[2] does, I connect to dp://192.168.1.98:1234, which is where my application sends the data. But I cannot see any image being displayed whatsoever.

Any guidance on how I can interpret a JPG stream using a UDP Server (such as VLC media player), or guidance on what modiciations needed on the UDP client side is greately appreciated.